# Reference child table with a main table

Tags: php, mysql, database

In my database I have a jobs table which you can say is the main table in my database. I have a column called *category* and this column points to a table called *category* which holds different categories.

Picking up the concept of *foreign keys*,I made turned the column *categories* into a foreign key, which looks at the categories table.

[image: Foreign Key]

In my categories table I make sure it points to the ID. 
[image: Implementation of FK]

When I run my webpage it prints out the value 1 in the category column, when in theory should it not print "*Driving"*?
[image]

```
function getJobDetails($job,$cat){
//this connects to the database
include "connectToDatabse.php";

//show me the results from job, where category is like cat vice versa
$results = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM job WHERE category LIKE '$cat%' OR title LIKE '$job'");
$str = "<table>";                       //prints out table
$str .= "<td>" ."Title" . "</td>";      //first row
$str .= "<td>" ."Reference" . "</td>";  //N row...
$str .= "<td>" ."Salary(£)" . "</td>";
$str .= "<td>" ."Description" . "</td>";
$str .= "<td>" ."Category" . "</td>";
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $ref = $row['reference'];
    $link = "<form method='get' action='apply.php' name='edit'>
         <input type='hidden' name='referenceNumber' value='$ref'>
         <input type='submit' value='$ref'>
    </form>";
    $str .= "<tr>";
    $str .= "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
    $str .= "<td>" . $row['reference'] . "</td>";
    $str .= "<td>" . $row['salary'] . "</td>";
    $str .= "<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
    $str .= "<td>" . $row['category'] . "</td>";
    $str .= "<td> " .$link . "</td>";
    $str .= "</tr>";
}
$str .= "</table>";
echo $str;
}
```

The above code is a function that returns the data in the job table.

Edit: referring to the question, since the categories column is pointing to the category table, should it not refer the data back to the job table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it shouldn't. You're missunderstanding foreign-keys. They do not change the data you get, they only tell the database system 'hey, this references somthing else, **if** this other entry gets updated or deleted, please do X (update, delete, ...) with this entry here'. You'd still need a join to get the expected result:

```
SELECT ..., category.title FROM job LEFT JOIN category ON category.id = job.category
```

Comment: I was thinking with a different logic, but it looks my MySQL is different. So when I do a query, I need to join both tables together? Hence you used the "Join" keyword?

Comment: Yes, when you need data from more than one table you need to join.

Comment: $results = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM job LEFT JOIN category ON category.idcategory = job.category'); 

Sorry if the formatting is bad:

I select all  from the job table, and join the column category with the column in the category table with the ID and that gives returns the result back to the category in the job table. 

I echoed result, and the return is still one, when it should be "Driving". Where did i go wrong with the query?

Comment: The result of `category` is still one because thats what it is in the database, you have to use the `title`, because thats the field where the real name is stored. You have access to this field because of the join.

Comment: Great, explanation was simple, took me sometime with trial and error, but thanks for backing me up till the end!